# Getting a specific Attributes inside a parent class from a child without passing parent's attributes into child class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, attributes, parent-child

How can I get access to a specific attribute in a parent class from it's child class.
In code below it says Student has no attribute "Schname" I want to get that from Student class

```
class School():
   def __init__(self,Name,Room,Teacher,Student):
       self.Schname = Name
       self.Schroom = Room
       self.Schteacher = Teacher
       self.Schstudent = Student     
class Student(School):
  def __init__(self):
      self.name = []
      self.grade=[]
      self.ID=[]
      super().__init__()
  def StudentData(self,name,grade,ID):
      self.name.insert(0,name)
      self.grade.insert(0,grade)
      self.ID.insert(0,ID)
  def StudentInfo(self):
      for i in range(len(self.name)):
          print(f"{self.name[i]} is in {self.Schname}")
```

Comment: Those are instance attributes, which belong to the *instance*, not the class. You would have to somehow run code that assigns it to the instance for a `Student` instance. **Mostly** this would be achieved through running `School.__init__` somehow on that instance

Comment: you mean using `School.__init__` instead of `self.Schname`?? or instead of `super().__init__`?? I tried both, its not working

Comment: You can do it in any of those ways. If you don't want to pass `Name,Room,Teacher,Student` you are going to have to initialize them *somehow*

Comment: still not working!!! what should I do????

Comment: School is a superclass of Student. It needs to be initialised with Name, Room, Teacher, Student. You're not doing that

Comment: I dont want to pass them into Student class. Is there any way to do it without passing them into child class?

Comment: @Ehsand what you are asking for fundamentally doesn't make sense. Again, *you are working with instances*. How would the driver code look like? You must instantiate a `Student`, e.g `student = Student()`, but even more importantly, **student shouldn't inherit from school**. Students *are not* schools, schools *have* students.

Comment: What im asking is there any way to get access to a specific attribute in a parent class from its child class without passing all parent's attributes to child one!!???